# json.load gives error when loading a file with latin character

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8, openshift

I am working on a python project and I am really confused about this whole utf-8/latin-1 encoding/decoding subject.

My linux system is an Openshift free account.

I am trying to load a file which contains a json data object.  The object has an entry that contains a latin character.

**test.json:**

```
 {
 "name" : "Corazón"
 }
```

When I load it on my Windows system I don't get an error but the result after the json.load is:

**Windows Output:**

CorazÃ³n

**Openshift Linux system trackback**:

```
data = json.load(data_file, encoding='utf-8')
 File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 271, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
 File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is:

```
import json

with open("test.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file, encoding='utf-8')

print(data['name'])
```

I have tried different encodings ('utf-8', 'ascii', 'latin-1') and they all give me the same results.  I obviously am missing something here.  Plus as you can see I get different results from windows and linux python.

How should I configure the json.load so it can load the file correctly on both Windows and linux python systems?

**Update 1**

I have ran some more tests. The 'test.json' file is utf-8 encoded and still gives me the above results.  When I encode the file as ISO 8859-1 the Windows output is correct but the linux out still results in the error.

I have even cut and pasted the test.json file from this SO question to run my tests to be on the same page as everybody else.

**Update 2**

If I convert my test.json file to 'Windows-1252' format the windows output is correct.  The linux box still results in the same error.  I'm not sure why the windows box does not work the the file is converted to utf-8.

Comment: Using this code on my Linux system works perfectly fine.  Maybe try rewriting that part of the file?

`print data['name']`
gives me Corazón

Comment: My production development system is an Openshift free account.  I wonder if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Why is it still incorrect on my Windows system?

Comment: Are you saving that JSON file using UTF-8 encoding? Are you sure the loaded object is wrong, or are you *trying to print* the object?

Comment: See my updated question as well as the comments in the other answer.  It's working on Windows now but not the Openshift linux box.

Comment: Yes, but loading an UTF-8 encoded file should work equally well. Please post your complete script, *including where you output your data*.

Comment: And also make sure you are running the code you are posting here. `json.load(data_file, encoding='utf-8')` will **not** output an error message involving the `'ascii' codec`.

Comment: It still is not working for me.  I have updated my question with new info.

Comment: I also added the traceback with the ascii error

Comment: So you're using Python 3. That's important, as Python 2 and Python 3 handle unicode / bytes differently. I'll update my answer then

Comment: Yes,  I'm using python 3.3.  I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3, the character encoding / decoding is handled by the file object itself. Specify the encoding in the `open()` call:

```
import json
with open("test.json", encoding='utf-8') as data_file:                           
    data = json.load(data_file)

print(data['name'])
```

It will correctly load the file on both platforms, *if* the file is correctly encoded as UTF-8.

It will definitely never raising the `UnicodeDecodeError` error you showed, because it's not using the `ascii` codec.

If you output to the console code page must contain all the characters you're printing, otherwise `print()` will raise an `UnicodeEncodeError` error.

I recommend you **do not** fall back to the `ISO 8859-1` codec. Those codecs should be considered legacy codecs on the internet. Sticking to UTF-8 will save you a lot of other headaches with handling names (and other text) in different languages.

Comment: You just copied his question code, it doesn't work for him, and the question is why?

Comment: @BigOldTree I pointed that out above: his question code is correct. But I don't think the error actually comes from that code (since he also posted an UnicodeDecodeError involving the 'ascii' codec).

Comment: It still is not working for me.  I have updated my question with new info.

Comment: @thanks roeland.  I actually tried putting the 'encoding='utf-8')  in the json.load arguments which did not work.  I missed it in the actual 'open' statement. Thanks again.  I'm still confused why it worked on windows and not linux but I'm happy :)